# Error al generar fichero excel

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación .NET 3.5 en Visual Studio 2015, que entre otras cosas lee de una base de datos y con la información genera un excel.
Estoy teniendo un problema al generar el archivo Excel, lo curioso es que cuando ejecuto la aplicacion desde la maquina virtual, una VMware® Workstation 14 Pro, me genera bien el excel en la ruta del host, sin embargo cuando lanzo el compilado en el host me da un error, y tiene que ver en como se forma la ruta donde guardar el fichero.

Actualmente la ruta se calcula asi:

```
ruta = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
wb.SaveAs(ruta + @"\Informe_" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + ".xlsx");
```

Como he dicho cuando lanzo el programa desde el VS2015 me genera el informe correctamente, sin embargo cuando lo lanzo desde el host me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente he podido debugear un poco y lo que se ve es que la ruta se crea de manera incorrecta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Nota. Se ve una linea negra en la imagen, eso lo he pintado para quitar el nombre del cliente y que se vea que ahi existe un texto normal, sin simbolos raros ni nada.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado lo que dice el mensaje con las posibles causas?, cuando generas el archivo y tienes error, ¿has eliminado las instancias de Excel que puedan estar abiertas? ' lo digo porque yo también tuve este problema: me sale un error al crear el archivo Excel, detengo la ejecución, pero reviso en el administrador de tareas que la instancia de Excel está abierta.

Comment: Y esa ruta existe?

Comment: Eso tiene pinta de ser un problema o bien de permisos, o como dice @MauricioAriasOlave que alguna instancia de Excel tiene abierto el archivo.

Comment: Ahora que releeo tu pregunta. En que es incorrecta la ruta?

Comment: @gbianchi Si, la ruta existe, como dice Mauricio si que se queda la instancia de excel abierta en memoria, lo cual me sorprende porque en el finally hago un ReleaseComObject para el Sheet, Book y Application...

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es que lanzandolo desde la maquina virtual me cree bien los ficheros en el host, y sin embargo lanzandolo desde el propio host no lo haga...

Comment: @Veelicus dices: `Finalmente he podido debugear un poco y lo que se ve es que la ruta se crea de manera incorrecta.` ¿cuál es la manera correcta de la ruta? considera usar otra ruta y en vez de esto: `+ DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() +` usa: `string nombre_archivo = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss") +`. Sin saber de la versión de Excel que tengas en la máquina virtual "si de pronto, la carpeta que hospedará el excel tiene permisos suficientes", creo que es mas un tema de configuración que del código.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque atiende a un problema de configuración y no esta relacionado a programación como el OP expone inicialmente. El problema puede ser difícilmente reproducido.